# uwp frame content binding

Tags: c++, binding, frame, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with binding. I have a gridview and i want to display Frames in it. The Frames should display the pages that are stored in the ItemsSource vector. But for some reason it is not displayed.

static hardcoded it works:

xaml

```
<Frame x:Name="testFrame"/>
```

c++

```
testFrame->Content = ref new TrainPanel;
```

Now i added a vector to my MainPage and store the TrainPanel in there:

h

```
Vector<Platform::Object^>^ m_frameList;
```

c++

```
m_frameList->Append(ref new TrainPanel);
panelGrid->ItemsSource = m_frameList;
```

XAML

```
    <GridView x:Name="panelGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="{Binding width}" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame x:Name="templateFrame" Content="{Binding Object}" Height="693" Width="Auto"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

and my TrainPanel has a property called Object:

```
#pragma once

#include "TrainPanel.g.h"
#include "TrainManager.h"
#include "Train.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

namespace TrainControl
{
/// <summary>
/// Eine leere Seite, die eigenständig verwendet werden kann oder auf die innerhalb eines Rahmens navigiert werden kann.
/// </summary>
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class TrainPanel sealed
{
public:
    TrainPanel();

    virtual ~TrainPanel();

    property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Platform::Object^>^ TrainList
    {
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Platform::Object^>^ get()
        {
            if (m_trainList == nullptr)
                m_trainList = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::Object^>();
            return m_trainList;
        }
    }

    property Platform::Object^ Object
    {
        Platform::Object^ get() { return this; }
    }

private:
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::Object^>^ m_trainList;
    Train^ m_currentTrain;
    bool m_sliderHolding;

private:
    void closePanel_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);

    void ctNameCombo_DropDownOpened(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e);
    void ctNameCombo_SelectionChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e);

    void ctSlider_ValueChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs^ e);
    void ctSlider_ManipulationStarted(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs^ e);
    void ctSlider_ManipulationCompleted(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs^ e);

    void ctChangeDirection_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
    void ctSounds_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
};
}
```

But it does not work. The page is not displayed.
Any ideas why the binding does not work??

Comment: Could you show us your complete code of the `TrainPanel`?

Comment: Do you need the cpp as well?